# How would I use a video player thats embedded through a script tag with react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I am trying to dynamically output some video content using an api (jwplayer). The api returns me some data to put in a script tag for instance:
    .js">

This tag works perfectly with plain html, but doesn't work with react jsx. How can I use this with a react component?

Answer (score 0):

Try this package `react-jwplayer` on npm just add your videoId to that component.

`import JWPlayer from 'react-jwplayer';
 <JWPlayer videoId="<your-id-here>" />`